# Grub Boot Error After Ubuntu Update

Tags: 10.04, dual-boot, grub2

I've installed Ubuntu 10.04 with dual boot to Windows XP. I put it on auto-update. It was updating grub and after a restart all it says is;

```
error:no such device: <hex number>
```

With a grub rescue prompt.

I'm in panic mode right now as it's my mother's office computer and it might have some serious repercussions for her tomorrow. What should I do?

**Update:** It appears that the partition structure has been corrupted since it only displays (hd0) on 
    ls

Comment: Could you post the results of [bootinfoscript](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/) in pastebin?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the upgrade messed the mbr (was it an upgrade from 1.9x grub to 2.0?)

You can try restoring grub it using a livecd:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

I didn't understand how you came up to conclusion that your hard drive partitions has been corrupted? can you try access the drives using the livecd?

Answer (score 0):

[Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com) has some tools for partition recovery.  If that doesn't work, you might be able to rescue the files directly with [this](http://www.data-recovery-linux.com/), although I haven't used it.

Comment: I can't download 147 MB plus, right now. Is there something I can do with a live CD?